# Htaccess query string to another

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url like:

```
shop/products.html?search_limiter=full&keyword1=apple
```

I want to rewrite this url to :

```
index.php?route=product/search&search=apple&description=true
```

using apache `.htaccess`

I try :

```
Redirect 301 /shop/products.html?search_limiter=full&keyword1=apple     http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=apple&description=true
```

but it did not work.

Is there any way ?

Comment: `Redirect` isn't going to be flexible enough to do this well; you'll want `mod_rewrite` but you'll need to use a `RewriteCond` to match on the query string in the first place : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite on a querystring you have to use `RewriteCond` to match on the querystring first - you can then use that in the `RewriteRule` with a `%N` type match.

This will perform the rewrite you want (with any search term, not just *"apple"*):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} shop/products.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search_limiter=full&keyword1=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?route=product/search&search=%1&description=true [NC,L,R=301]
```

If you **don't** want to actually change the URL in the address bar, just the resource that's being loaded, leave **R=301** (http 301 redirect) out of the flags.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My keywords has utf8 chars.So not rewrite. Can you help me abouth that? http://www.example.com/shop/products.html?search_limiter=full&keyword1=%C5%9Fi%C5%9Fe

Comment: Just use ([^?\ /]+) for utf8. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think `\w` (any "word" character) should work as well... @Ussosan